# Problem with launching Steam [K-Ubuntu 16.04]

Tags: steam

Whenever I try to launch Steam the icon just flashes for a few seconds, but when I try to run it in the Terminal it displays this:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
[2016-09-28 18:35:05] Startup - updater built Sep 20 2016 18:20:24
SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
```

How to solve it?

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu @Fext. You don't need to say thanks on questions and answers. Just make questions and answers clear and direct. I know that you tried to be polite, but it's not necessary here.

Comment: What graphics card and what drivers are you running? *X error* suggests a problem with graphics.

Comment: AMD Radeon R7 250X 2.2 GHz, i'll check the drivers :)

Answer (score 0):

All the old hints didn't help me personally any longer, but maybe it'll help you to fix this annyoing steam 64bit update problem

```
cd .steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak
cd .steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak

LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6' DISPLAY=:0 steam
```

Unfortunaley it didn't help with my steam version, but many other had success
-> [Ubuntu LP 1527669](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/steam/+bug/1527669)

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.10 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
[2016-10-18 19:47:49] Startup - updater built Oct 13 2016 00:47:16
SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
```

More hints to solve the problem
[link](https://manerosss.wordpress.com/2016/05/16/how-to-fix-steam-not-running-with-open-source-drivers-on-arch-linux/)